# FB Graph API returns 200 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

using app token to get fb url pages likes but seeing this message.
"(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/"

Any idea when it would be available ?

Comment: No. It would say on that page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not Facebook customer service.